# Why is this makefile not building the dependencies, but only when using variables

Tags: c++, makefile, code-generation

I have a makefile to generate some headers and cpp files from a yaml file.

```
../api/%.h ../api/%.cpp : ../idl/%.yml
    $(info Generating api files from $<)
    $(IDL_TO_CPP_EXE) --input $< --output $(basename $@)

IDL_HEADERS=$(IDL_INPUTS:../idl/%.yml=../api/%.h)
IDL_CPPS=$(IDL_INPUTS:../idl/%.yml=../api/%.cpp)

all: $(IDL_HEADERS) $(IDL_CPPS)
    $(info The dependencies are $(IDL_HEADERS) $(IDL_CPPS))

IDL_INPUTS +=../idl/common_api/CommonTypes.yml
```

When I run it, it outputs the following, but without generating the .h and .cpp file. I've checked they aren't there, so it's not a timestamp issue.

```
The dependencies are ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.h ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.cpp
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

If I manually expand the variables to the following, then it suddenly starts to work! The console output from the logging is exactly the same, and I've been careful to avoid things like hidden characters.

```
all: ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.h ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.cpp
    $(info The dependencies are $(IDL_HEADERS) $(IDL_CPPS))
```

Why is this makefile working with explicit dependencies, but not with variables?

UPDATE:

```
all: $(IDL_HEADERS) $(IDL_CPPS)
    $(info The dependencies are $^)
    $(info The dependencies should be $(IDL_HEADERS) $(IDL_CPPS))
```

outputs:

```
The dependencies are
The dependencies should be ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.h ../api/common_api/CommonTypes.cpp
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Comment: First, in your recipe for `all` you should print `$^` not the actual variables: the automatic variable `$^` contains the actual prerequisites that make thinks `all` has.  Second, you should run `make -d` and examine the (very long) debug output to see why make thinks that the prerequisites don't need to be built.

Comment: @MadScientist using `$^` was useful. It's showing me that it thinks the prerequisites are empty.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an ordering problem. When the `all` rule is parsed, I hadn't set the `IDL_INPUTS` variable.
`IDL_INPUTS` gets set later, and the the `all` rule was run after that, showing the new updated values.

Comment: That's why it's important that you ensure that the examples in the question you ask really show the actual problem you're seeing: here if you'd created your example the same way as your real makefile, we would have immediately told you what was wrong.  But if you try to run your example you showed us, it would work fine, so we couldn't help.